# How to Resolve Memory Leak and Cancel All Subscriptions Error in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have one warning in the console for my React app that mentions a memory leak with instructions. I'm not sure how to **refactor my code** to incorporate **componentWillUnmount**.

I **do** have useEffect() and JS promise code to pull and render data from a Firebase database but the error does not mention that component.

**Please read the full warning error below here:**

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the 
componentWillUnmount method.
        in Nav (at Home.js:32)
        in div (at Home.js:30)
        in DashHome (created by Context.Consumer)
```

**Nav.js code:**

```
class Nav extends Component {
  state = {
    isSignedIn: true
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: user })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="side-nav">
        <Nav vertical>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="#">Home</NavLink>
          </NavItem>

          {this.state.isSignedIn ? (
            <div>
              <Button onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</Button>
            </div>
          ) : (
              <Redirect to="/" />
            )}

        </Nav>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

**Home.js component (some code)**

```
export default function Home() {
    const generateData = (value, length = 5) =>
        d3.range(length).map((item, index) => ({
            date: index,
            value: value === null || value === undefined ? Math.random() * 100 : value
        }));

    const [data, setData] = useState(generateData(0));
    const changeData = () => {
        setData(generateData());
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setData(generateData());
        },
        [!data]
    );
```

I read about AbortController API in a tutorial but I'm not using Fetch in my app.

Thank you for taking a look! Please feel free to post any code refactoring ideas to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns an unsubscribe function when you call it.

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        // handle it
    });
```

You should call this function in componentWillUnmount like this.

```
let unsubscribe;
class Nav extends Component {
  state = {
    isSignedIn: true
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({
        isSignedIn: user
      })
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    unsubscribe()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond Chase! :)

Comment: Sorry, you put exactly what you had before with the setState. It should work now that it won't fire after the component unmounts. I put it in the componentDidMount in the bottom snippet.

Comment: No worries. Sorry, I saw that in hindsight. Thank you so much for including the order of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check all functions that update component state. That error normally occurs when you update a state that was not defined in **state = {}**.
For example;
Having your initial state when the component was mounted as

```
    state = {
        isSignedIn: true,
    };
```

And then somewhere in your code, you update a state with no predefined refs,

```
    this.setState({ someOtherRefs: certainValue });
```

React will complain since **someOtherRefs** was not defined when component was mounted.

All try to check whether you used correct spelling in state update functions.

Comment: Thank you so much javarce for responding! :) Okay, I will check all my components that change state to double check.